# Spring boot Bean exception: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, mysql-workbench

I am trying to run a spring boot application which is made by someone else. I have tried to attach my local database to the application but when I run this, it gives the following error;

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).

I am new to this and I can't find out what is the problem. Some details:

where xxx = name of the database.

Workbench:

```
Name: Local instance wampmysqld64
Host: localhost
Port: 3306
Server: MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Version: 5.7.18-log
Connector: C++ 1.1.4 
Login User: root
Current User: root@localhost
SSL: Disabled
```

And the server is up and running.

**EDIT**

**pom.xml**

```
<project>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>****</groupId>
<artifactId>****</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
      <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

**EDIT2**

**Application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

ng.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

**Application.java**

```
package gdprserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
}
```

**EDIT3**

I run the Spring boot application with CMD using the command: `java -jar xxx.jar`

Comment: you sure your `application.properties` file on classpath (ideally at `src/main/resources`? Also show your `@SpringBootApplication` class

Comment: The application.properties is located at `src/main/resources` yes.

Comment: No spring-boot-starter-jdbc or spring-boot-starter-data-jpa?

Comment: After fixing your dependencies, if Spring for unknown reasons still can't find the driver class to instantiate (it should deduce it for mySQL from your URL for that driver) you can add a property explicitly naming it like this:  `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: Thanks for your help @GerryMantha. Unfortunetally this does not solve the problem.

Comment: You should show more of your POM file... at least all the spring-boot/starter stuff.  Also did you double check that your driver dependency is indeed being added to your classpath and included in your deployment assembly?

Comment: @GerryMantha I am sorry, but I do not understand what you mean with that. How can I check this?

Comment: I am missing a (i think important) property : `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in your application.properties. (extending Gerry's answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to run my application with Eclipse.

Before I tried to run my application using Java Application -> SpringApplication with the main class: `org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication`. Changing the main class to xxx.Application (where xxx is the projectname) works.

Answer (score 5):

```
package com.fyakuthibernatespringboot.demo;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding just a code example without explanation is not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The exception "Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE." is caused by Spring being unable to find the properties that define the database.  It's telling us that it doesn't have the information necessary to create/configure the data-source.

It's possible that it's an IDE related issue.  Build your jar using maven and try run it. If you get the same exception, open the jar and look inside it to ensure it's being added correctly.